# += with multiple variables in python

Tags: python, increment

I'm trying to increment multiple variables at the same time and stick it into one line. What would be the most pythonic way to do this if there is a way?

Comment: The Pythonic way is to not do it on one line.

Comment: The any language at all ever way is not to do it all one one line, with the exception of Perl, of course. :)

Comment: @MattBall It's the simplest way to update multiple variables simultaneously. Here's [a Python core developer telling you when to do it in one line, and why (@34:00)](http://pyvideo.org/video/1780/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-pytho)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to write a single line, you can try multiple assignment, but without the `+=` syntax:

```
a, b, c = a+1, b+1, c+1
```

Or for a more pythonic solution, avoid the one-liner:

```
a += 1
b += 1
c += 1
```

Comment: I like my code in one liners I'm starting to think this might actually just be the simplest way.

Comment: @user3255511 you will have a lot of mortal enemies in the future if you don't format nicely your code, xD

Comment: You will also curse yourself if you ever have to maintain your own code in ... oh ... 2 months later. I bet you also don't like comments.

Comment: @user3255511 Not trying to preach here...I know "religious" debates are out of place at SO and I'm not trying to start one about which is "better", but *if* as you say you prefer compact syntax that crams multiple actions into a single line, you'd probably be more comfortable with Perl. Matt Ball's comment sums it up nicely. On the flip side, the Perlish way is to do it all on one line along with at least two or three other things.

Comment: The two examples provided here are **not** equivalent. The former provides simultaneous updates, which is part of the OP's request, but the latter does not.

Comment: @AirThomas didn't you read the clarification? _avoid the one liner_, it's clearer that way, hence more Pythonic.

Comment: It doesn't matter how Pythonic the multi-line version is, if a chance exception thrown between one line and the next will cause the entire program to fail. And that can be a difficult bug to anticipate. Imagine you are writing this answer for someone who next year will be writing a guidance module for a $125 million Mars orbiter...

Answer (score 3):

Say you have

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
```

after you define:

```
def add1(x):
    return x+1
```

You can do:

```
print(map(f,[a, b, c])) # prints [2, 3, 4]
```

which means that the following line will give you what you want:

```
a, b, c = map(add1,[a, b, c])
```

which is a bit easier to do than:

```
a, b, c = a+1, b+1, c+1
```

in case you have a big array. Further, you maintain readability *and* get your "one liner".

Comment: This requires casting it into a list and that makes me worry about more complexity but useful information. It gives me ideas on how to finally make use of the lambda function.

Comment: @user3255511 of course, you can define the lambda "inline" (inside the map)